# Problems with my slide gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few problems with the sliding gallery I added:

1. the buttons stuck below the gallery instead of its sides. (I tried to give them 'display: inline-block' (?)).
2. I want to divide the `#gallrey` div into 2. Which contain the `#slideGallery` & `#galleryDescription`. The div `#galleryDescription` contains `<p>` that is stuck at the bottom instead of top or center.

This is the format I want `#gallery` to have:

[button left][#slideGallery DIV][button right][#galleryDescription DIV]

Hope you understand me. :)

Here is my code:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

#gallery {
  width: 620px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#gallerySlide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#galleryDescription {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#glryDesc {
  /* (glryDesc = gallery description)  */
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="gallerySlide">
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/slide1.png" />
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/slide2.png" />
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/slide3.jpg" />
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/slide4.jpg" />

    <button class="btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>

  </div>
  <div id="galleryDescription">
    <p id="glryDesc">This is gonna be the description of the slide gallery. The gallery is very nice. Also the description !</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the edit.
Second, there is the right brackets over there.

Comment: #gallerySlide {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;

    top: 0;
    left:0;
}

Do you mean to the code above?, If so it written on mu CSS fils and on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

You had way too many `width`s that were contradicting with each other. I had to compromise a little on the different sizes. Try adjusting them yourself.

`left`, `top` and `right` are properties do not work on elements that do not have a specific `position` set (`relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`). Default position is `static`.

I used `flex` containers and `justify-content`, `align-items` to align the items accordingly. Read up on them.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);
function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  height: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  display: none;
}

#gallery{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 660px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#gallerySlide {
  display: flex;
  width: 49%;
}

#glryDesc { /* (glryDesc = gallery description)  */
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="gallerySlide">
         <button class="btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
         <img class="mySlides" src="images/slide1.png" />
         <img class="mySlides" src="images/slide2.png" />
         <img class="mySlides" src="images/slide3.jpg" />
         <img class="mySlides" src="images/slide4.jpg" />
         <button class="btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
    <div id="galleryDescription">
         <p id="glryDesc">This is gonna be the description of the slide gallery. The gallery is very nice. Also the description !</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it solved the problems, but create other.
The images is on original size instead of 280x280px.
The text overrides part of the images.

Comment: You should play around with it. It does not override for me.

Comment: Ok, I handled it. Thank you !